# Active Expensive Queries and Recent Expensive Queries Meaning

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, activity-monitor

I am trying to understand the active expensive queries and recent expensive queries in Activity Monitor. What is expensive means here? Does it means expensive in term of cpu, block, memory, reads?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on what column you sort by. To dig deeper, I suggest you read the source code that these are on. I blogged about AM a while ago, here is a part from that blog post:

The “Recent Expensive Queries” pane:

This shows the most expensive queries, based on what column you sort on, executed since the last snapshot. If you have, say, a 10 second snapshot interval, you will only see the queries executed during these 10 seconds. AM uses a procedure named #am_get_querystats to collect the information. There are a few things going on inside this procedure, but at the most basic level, it uses sys.dm_exec_query_stats and sys.dm_exec_requests to get queries from cache and currently executing queries. It then does some processing and store the result in temp tables so we later can sort on different columns depending on what metric we are interested in. I suggest that you spend some time with the source code if you want to dig deeper.

The “Active Expensive Queries” pane:

This is very straight forward. It executes a query which uses sys.dm_exec_requests joined to a few other DMVs.

Here's a link to my blog post: http://sqlblog.karaszi.com/explaining-activity-monitor/

Comment: I thought activity monitor is build using native code rather than SQL

Comment: What do you mean by "native code"? The information has to come from somewhere, and that somewhere is SQL server and the only interface to SQL Server is SQL. Then of course the client app uses an API and is written in some language, but the interface to SQL Server is SQL.

Comment: Actually SQL Server is built with C/C++ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server. I thought they built the same with C/C++

Comment: YEs, I said in my earlier comment that the client app is written in some language (C++ in this case). But the point is that the information is coming from somewhere, and that is from a number of SQL queries submitted to SQL Server. See my blog post, it is all in there, if you don't believe me. :-)

Comment: I have a feeling that you wonder in the end if the computations are done in T-SQL or C++. From the trace, it seems that they (at least the majority of them) are done in T-SQL. If they were done in C++, we would have to rely 100% on what was documented on this by MS - nothing in this case. Thanks to it being T-SQL, we can reverse-engineer based on a trace and the T-SQL code.

Comment: Thanks Tibor for clarification :)